# Alternative way to check if a Window is a Popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a page that can be opened from either my domain or as a popup opened from a different domain. In this page, I have to check it by Javascript if it was opened as a popup or if it was directly opened by it's URL and do some stuff.

Right now, I'm following the widely suggested approach, using the `window.opener` attribute...

```
if (window.opener != null)
    // It is a popup
else
    // It's not a popup
```

... but recently I've been facing an IE issue, which isn't filling up that attribute.

Could anyone suggest me a different approach to accomplish this? The IE issue is probably unavoidable without changing some windows configurations.

Btw, when I say that the page is being opened as a popup, I'm talking about a `window.open()` call that opens a new window.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm just going to go ahead and ask the obvious: Why do you need to know if the window is popup? What is different?

Comment: I need to do some layout changes in both cases. I know, it's messy.

Comment: I don't know of a reliable way to do this. If you could modify the JS code that opens the popup then _maybe_. Can you modify the URL or some query parameter? IE. `my.domain.com/index.php?opener=popup`

Comment: Nope, I guess that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Check [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) inside the popup.

```
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/mydomain/i)) {
    // page was opened directly
}
else {
    // page was opened by other domain
    // this is a popup
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please. How do you use the referrer to detect if a window is a popup?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen the pertinent detail seems to be not whether it is a popup but rather whether it was opened from OP's domain or some other. The referrer is the source of that information, no?

Comment: Are you talking about checking if it's a cross domain call? That's not what I'm asking...

Comment: @EvertonAgner it sounds like, in your use case, cross-domain and popup are the same scenario. Is there a third (or fourth) scenario where the page can be opened as a popup from your domain or directly by the other domain?

Comment: It is currently and technically the same scenario, but I would prefer to do something not considering just the domain. Anyways, if I can't come up with a solution like that, I'll follow this different approach.

Comment: If the page is opened from another domain it's useful to note that most browsers don't pass the referrer anymore; to improve user privacy.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Exactly. Chrome passed the referrer while IE didn't. Well, I'm back to square one.